# Line-breaking a regexp in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, literals

As readability is somewhat absent in the below shown Regular expression literal, I would like to split it up over several lines. How would I do this and what does need to change/be escaped?

```
regex = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i;
```

Thanks

Comment: you can't. Also i doubt it will increase the readability that much.

Comment: what this regex actually do? there may b possible shorter and optimize regex

Comment: If you're up for it, you could just use a string, and the `RegExp` constructor, that could allow you to break the expression down into _"meaningful"_ parts... Although, I must say: it looks like this expression is going to be used on HTML, in which case: Just parse the DOM

Comment: Could you use a comment to explain what your regex does? Also, I would like to know what it does, out of curiosity.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs It's a regex for URL validation I found somewhere that illustrated my question. I reckon that it could be more effective however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support multiline regexes. You could construct a regex from a string, though:

```
r = new RegExp( 
"\\b" + 
"(" + 
"(?:[a-z][\\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)" + 
"(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+" + 
"(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’])" + 
")", "i")
```

(I hope I got the string building syntax correct - I'm not a JavaScript person, so if this doesn't work, let me know)

Comment: You don't need the backslashes (in fact they will produce syntax errors), JS will automatically look on the next line.